# How to group my results and have all rows shown?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT i.itemsname
     , i.itemsprice
     , i.itemsdescrip
     , c.catname
     , c.catdes
     , c.status
     , c.collapse
     , c.catid 
  FROM items i 
  LEFT
  JOIN categories c
    ON c.catid = i.catid 
 WHERE i.restid 
   AND c.restid =12 
GROUP 
    BY c.catid
```

that is my query at the moment but I would like to have something like this....

[image: Example]

but this is what I'm getting:

[image: This is what I'm getting]

Comment: you cant use group in the query as it's an aggregate, if you use PDO you can do FETCH_GROUP with the first column being the group field to fetch.  This will create and array where the "Grouped" field is the id of a subset of the data.  Or you can manually build it when pulling from the data.  What you want is your DB data like this `[catid1 => [ 0=>[... row data ..], 1=> [..]], catid2 => [..]] `  This way your data is organized when you go to build the table.  Which should be trivial with 2 foreach loops.  Sorry I'm to lazy to flesh out an answer, but it cant be done by query alone..

Comment: What you want is a sort by, and as you iterate, note the change in category and print accordingly -or- perform grouping after the results have been returned from the DB through manual array processing.

Comment: sorting will basically kill any performance you get from your query, it should be avoided if possible.  This may be fine on small datasets with indexes, but if you have a couple 100k rows, it's a big hit... sorry I'm used to dealing with 100k to several million records.  Most being 80million.  Besides then you have to track the category name, data structure solves these issues.

Comment: Alternativly, you could do a subquery to improve performance for the sorting, by pulling the category name and id and sort, then in the outer query, join with the tmp table that creates and pull the rest of the data.  Which will be sorted via the inner query and the join.

Comment: my code looks like this ....       $cat = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT items.itemsname, items.itemsprice, items.itemsdescrip, categories.catname, categories.catdes, categories.status, categories.collapse, categories.catid FROM items LEFT JOIN categories ON items.catid=categories.catid WHERE items.restid AND categories.restid =12 GROUP BY items.itemsid, categories.catid"); 
if($cat === FALSE) { 
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}
         
         
                  ?>
     
     
     <div class="accordion">
                        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">

Comment: <?php
 
while ($rowb = mysqli_fetch_array($cat)) {
echo "<div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <a href='#collapse{$rowb['catid']}'><div class='panel-heading {$rowb['status']}'>
                              <h3 class='panel-title'></a>
                                <a class='accordion-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion1' href='#collapse{$rowb['catid']}'> {$rowb['catname']}   <i class='fa fa-angle-right pull-right'></i>
                                </a>
                              </h3>

Comment: I cant read that, you can use back ticks in posts to do `code`, plus I don't do mysqli for like 5 years now ... so lol

Comment: Two observations: 1. You have a GROUP BY clause and no aggregating functions. Performance benefits aside, this is NEVER a good idea, and renders your present query nonsensical. 2. You have a WHERE condition applied to a LEFT JOINed table. This renders the KEFT JOIN as an INNER JOIN. Either change the join, or move the WHERE condition to the ON clause. Finally, for further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I lied in the comments, so With PDO (haven't tested it)

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare('SELECT
    categories.catname,
    items.itemsname,
    items.itemsprice,
    items.itemsdescrip,
    categories.catdes,
    categories.status,
    categories.collapse,
    categories.catid 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN categories ON items.catid=categories.catid 
WHERE items.restid AND categories.restid = :restid');

$stmt->execute([':restid' => 12]);

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP);



foreach($data as $catname => $rows){
    //echo group html stuff
    //echo "<dl>";
    //echo "<dt>$catname</dt>".;

    foreach($rows as $row){
       //echo row data stuff

      // echo "<dd> {stuff} </dd>";

    }
   //echo "</dl>";
}
```

I'll leave the html up to you.  But as I said you want a data structure like this

```
[
  'BREAKFASTS' => [
       0 => [ name => "wimpy hamburger", description => "bla bla", price => "$100,000"],
       1 => [ ... ]
  ],
  'SINGLE BURGERS' => [ ...]
]
```

> note that the first field after "SELECT" is by default the field used by FETCH_GROUP

See in this way, the first foreach can output the title of the category, which is `BREAKFASTS` for example.  Then the inner foreach can do the individual rows in the table.

Personally I would use a `dl`, `dt`, `dd` tag setup as my structure (hinted in the comments, i really am to lazy today to code all the html, `<sigh>`)

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dt.asp

**UPDATE**

You may want to check your query

```
    ...
 WHERE
    items.restid AND ...
```

Seems to be flawed, just saying.  I saw this while optomizing the query for sorting.

```
   SELECT
    c.catname,
    i.itemsname,
    i.itemsprice,
    i.itemsdescrip,
    c.catdes,
    c.status,
    c.collapse,
    c.catid 
FROM
    (
        SELECT c0.catid FROM categories AS c0 WHERE c0.restid = :restid SORT BY c0.catname
    ) AS t
JOIN
     categories AS c ON t.catid=c.catid 
LEFT JOIN 
    items AS i ON items.catid=categories.catid 
WHERE
     items.restid = ? //< this is the error/omission/strangeness i pointed out above.
```

So a few things to note, first you should base the query off the categories, as an empty category should be shown, while an item without a category will blow it all to bits ( basically, ie how can you group them by the category if they have none ) You'll wind up with some hodgepoge of items with no category at the end, of course based on your example I'm assuming a Many to One relationship.  For example One category can have Many items, and Many items can belong to a category.  (it's probably more ideal to do a Many to Many, but that's another story for another day)

The reason the above query is more optimized is the inner query, creates only a small temp table using the catid, And sorts on just the data from the cat table and only the data that is pulled by the where.

Then as we move to the outer query, they basically inherent the sort from the join, and we can pull the rest of the data from that.  It's typically about 2-10x faster this way (of course I haven't test this particular query) in theory.  Of course this is a bit more complex/advanced query and is optional, but it should improve sort performance if my mind is in the right place tonight... lol

Also I abbreviated your table names (alias), as I said I am lazy like that.  Sadly my answers are always so long, dont ask me how I see all these issues, it's just experience or how my dyslexic brain works?

Lastly, if you really must use mysqli, you can manually group them with something like this.

```
 $data = [];

 while(false !== ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())){
     $key = $row['catname'];
     if(!isset($data[$key]))  $data[$key] = [];

     $data[$key][] = $row;
}
```

It's all so prosaic (common place, non-poetic) at this point for me.

Good luck.

Comment: as you can tell I'm not very experienced lol. I have spent hours on it, but I will try sorting it out with the few points you have given me... if not would it be possible to send you what I have to correct it for me? I would be very grateful :)

Comment: It would be extremely difficult for me as I don't have your database, so I am working just in my head.

Comment: I would say, keep it simple to start, get the data structure right, use `print_r($data)` and use `echo "<pre>";` to keep the whitespace, then add the foreach loops and the html output.  Later if you have performance issues with sorting, you can do a more advanced query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT
categories.catname,
items.itemsname,
items.itemsprice,
items.itemsdescrip,
categories.catdes,
categories.catid 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN categories ON items.catid=categories.catid 
WHERE items.restid AND categories.restid = 12"); 
if($cat === FALSE) { 
die(mysqli_error()); 
}

$data = []; 
while ($rowb = mysqli_fetch_array($cat)) {
$key = $rowb['catname'];
if(!isset($data[$key]))  $data[$key] = [];
$data[$key][] = $rowb;

foreach($data as $catname => $rowbs){                     
echo " 
<dl><button class='accordiontry'><dt>$catname</dt></button>"; 

<div class='panel1'>

foreach($rowbs as $rowb){
echo"<div class='rmenu'>
<dd><span class='item'>{$rowb['itemsname']}</span>
<span class='price'>£{$rowb['itemsprice']}</span><br>
<span class='des'>{$rowb['itemsdescrip']}</span>  ";
}
echo"</div></dd>
</div></dl>";

}
}
}
```

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  now the problem is it displays the items as 

   Category 1 --> Item1
   Category 1 --> Item1 , Item2
   Category 1 ---> Item1, item2, item3
   instead of Category 1 ---> Item1, Item2, Item3
   What am I doing wrong?